# Vimeo: Get all albums related to a video

Tags: vimeo

Is it possible to get all albums releated to a specific video with the vimeo api 3.4?

I know, I can look in every album, which videos are in there, but this seems a bit hackish.
I'm looking for something like `GET/videos/{video_id}/albums` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

We unfortunately don't have an API endpoint for this right now, but it's on our roadmap for the next two weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The same is with channels and groups. Will there be and endpoint for them too?

Comment: Any progress on this? It has been two weeks and I for one could use this particular endpoint. Thanks.